# Problem in returning the key and value of an object after specifying function values

Tags: javascript

I have a function called `myObject` that returns an object by taking two parameters, the name of the `key` and the `value`.
The problem is that the parameters we give as `key` and `value` only consider and display the `value` but not the `key`.
You can see the output in the console.
please guide me

The desired output in the console :  `{"Number":12345}`

```js
const myObject = (key, value) => {
    return { key: value }
};
console.log(myObject("Number", 12345));
```

Comment: Put `key` in square brackets like `{ [key]: value }`

Comment: You'd probably want to read up on [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#computed_property_names)

Comment: Check https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#new_notations_in_ecmascript_2015 - the examples under `// Computed property names (ES2015)`

Answer (score -1):

You are creating an object with a key called `key`. Instead you want your function to look like this:

```js
const myObject = (key, value) => {
  return { 
    [key]: value
  }
};

console.log(myObject("Number", 12345))
```